# New relic infra agent not restarted

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, newrelic, infrastructure

We are using New Relic infrastructure agent from last 2 yrs but after 13th Nov 2019 suddenly its not working. Then I update the version of newrelic to 5.2.3.131. But the problem is not resolve. The problem is i’m unable to restart new relic infra agent.

I used below commands…
echo “license_key: ${NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY}” | sudo tee /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/newrelic-infra.repo https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/yum/el/6/x86_64/newrelic-infra.repo
sudo yum -q makecache -y --disablerepo=’*’ --enablerepo=‘newrelic-infra’
sudo yum install newrelic-infra -y
sudo initctl restart newrelic-infra

Application hosted aws elastic beanstalk.

I’m getting initctl: Unknown instance.

Deatails error are below…

INFO [7168] - [Application update pem.pem-staging.f6e105eb760.20191117-164558@668/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_1_PEM/Command 04-configure_new_relic] : Activity execution failed, because: license_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:–:-- --:–:-- --:–:-- 0
100 239 100 239 0 0 2091 0 --:–:-- --:–:-- --:–:-- 2096
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Package newrelic-infra-1.7.1-1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
initctl: Unknown instance:
(ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)

Answer (score 0):

in my case it looks:

.ebextensions/new_relic.yml

```
packages:
  yum:
    newrelic-sysmond: []
  rpm:
    newrelic: http://yum.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/x86_64/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm

commands:
  "01":
    command: nrsysmond-config --set license_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  "02":
    command: echo hostname=$SERVER_URL >> /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg
  "03":
    command: /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond start
```

You might not need '02' command

Comment: You are using centOs server?

Comment: i'm using elastic beanstalk. this ami-c2090428 for example

Answer (score 0):

Problem is new relic end. I have solved this temporarily by using below commands...

```
cat /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
ps aux | grep newrelic-infra
```

Just kill all processes returned by the ps command above with kill -9 pid1 pid2... 
Then start the service with sudo initctl start newrelic-infra 
It's now working fine.